# how to add a dot before each letter in a string in python

Tags: python

we get a string from user and want to lowercase it and remove vowels and add a '.' before each letter of it. for example we get 'aBAcAba' and change it to '.b.c.b' . two early things are done but i want some help with third one.

```
str = input()
str=str.lower()
for i in range(0,len(str)):
    str=str.replace('a','')
    str=str.replace('e','')
    str=str.replace('o','')
    str=str.replace('i','')
    str=str.replace('u','')
print(str)
for j in range(0,len(str)):
    str=str.replace(str[j],('.'+str[j]))
print(str)
```

Comment: Can you explain how `aBAcAba` becomes `.b.c.b` according to your rules?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen aftet removing the vowels from the string, all that's left is `bcb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- You should avoid the variable name `str` because this is used by a builtin, so I've changed it to `st`
- In the first part, no loop is necessary; `replace` will replace *all* occurrences of a substring
- For the last part, it is probably easiest to loop through the string and build up a new string. Limiting this answer to basic syntax, a simple `for` loop will work.

```
st = input()
st=st.lower()
st=st.replace('a','')
st=st.replace('e','')
st=st.replace('o','')
st=st.replace('i','')
st=st.replace('u','')
print(st)
st_new = ''
for c in st:
    st_new += '.' + c
print(st_new)
```

Another potential improvement: for the second part, you can also write a loop (instead of your five separate `replace` lines):

```
for c in 'aeiou':
    st = st.replace(c, '')
```

---

Other possibilities using more advanced techniques:

- For the second part, a regular expression could be used:

  - `st = re.sub('[aeiou]', '', st)`
- For the third part, a generator expression could be used:

  - `st_new = ''.join(f'.{c}' for c in st)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.join()` to place some character in between all the existing characters, and then you can use string concatenation to place it again at the end:

```
# st = 'bcb'
st = '.' + '.'.join(st)
# '.b.c.b'
```

As a sidenote, *please don't use `str` as a variable name*. It's the name of the "string" datatype, and if you make a variable named it then you can't properly work with other strings any more. `string`, `st`, `s`, etc. are fine, as they're not the reserved keyword `str`.

Comment: This always adds a dot, even when the string is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```py
z = "aBAcAba"

z = z.lower() 
newstring = ''
for i in z:
  if not i in 'aeiou':
    newstring+='.'
    newstring+=i  


print(newstring)
```

Here I have gone step by step, first converting the string to lowercase, then checking if the word is not vowel, then add a dot to our final string then add the word to our final string.

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the string into an array and then build a new string with the indexes of the array appending an "."
not too efficient but will work.

Answer (score 0):

This does everything.

```
import re

data    = 'KujhKyjiubBMNBHJGJhbvgqsauijuetystareFGcvb'

matches = re.compile('[^aeiou]', re.I).finditer(data)
final   = f".{'.'.join([m.group().lower() for m in matches])}"

print(final)

#.k.j.h.k.y.j.b.b.m.n.b.h.j.g.j.h.b.v.g.q.s.j.t.y.s.t.r.f.g.c.v.b
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all of you especially allani. the bellow code worked.

```
st = input()
st=st.lower()
st=st.replace('a','')
st=st.replace('e','')
st=st.replace('o','')
st=st.replace('i','')
st=st.replace('u','')
print(st)
st_new = ''
for c in st:
    st_new += '.' + c
print(st_new)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s = input()
s = s.lower()
for i in s:
    for x in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
        if i == x:
            s = s.replace(i,'')
new_s = ''
for i in s:
    new_s += '.'+ i
print(new_s)
```

Answer (score -2):

def add_dots(n):
return ".".join(n)
print(add_dots("test"))

def remove_dots(a):
return a.replace(".", "")
print(remove_dots("t.e.s.t"))

Comment: def add_dots(n):
    return ".".join(n)
print(add_dots("test"))
def remove_dots(a):
    return a.replace(".", "")
print(remove_dots("t.e.s.t"))

Comment: You may want to format your code - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and add an explanation